# MVC Hiding RouteValues Form Post from Url's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Working with Multiple Steps on a form and different views sharing one model.

On my second Step Form Post submit I am passing in my model to maintain the state.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("StepTwo", "Home", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "restrictionForm" }))   { %>
```

But I find when I hit submit and it works the way I want, my entire model and its attributes are now listed in the url which is not desirable.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ActionName("StepTwo")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult StepTwoPost(PostcodesModel model)
{
    try
    {
        _Provider.AddNewRestriction(model.Postcode, model.SelectedRestriction, model.RestrictionDescription, model.WildcardID);
        return View("StepThree", model);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ViewBag.PostCodeErrors = "<div class=\"errorMessage\">Error inserting restriction " + model.Postcode + ".</div><p>" + ex.Message + "</p>";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Anyway to now display model in URL this way ?

i.e.

```
http://localhost:/Home/StepThree?Postcode=1234&.....
```

Comment: So you are seeing your entire model posted in the querystring and you don't want it do? I tried reproducing that and I cant. When submit a form in MVC.net, the model is posted as form data in the body of the request. It seems like you are using MVC.net 2 (or at least aren't using Razor syntax). I am using MVC.net 4. Maybe they are different somehow?

Comment: Its MVC 4, I only see the entire model in querystring after passing model here in my form. <% using (Html.BeginForm("StepTwo", "Home", Model, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "restrictionForm" }))   { %>. But I need to pass so I can persist my model through Form Submits.

Comment: Could you post the entire view? I tried to reproduce it locally but haven't had the issue. Also can you look at the html generated by the view to make sure method="post"? On a side note, if you are using MVC 4 you should use Razor (cshtml pages). I just use it because its faster to type, but I think there are other differences too.

Answer (score 0):

can you post the complete view?,

how are are you rendering your Models values? if you are rendering them as routing data within the submit button these will cause them to appear on the URL, you should render them the model within HTML elements "Textbox" or "Hidden" for example and these values will be posted as form data